# How does one safely static_cast between unsigned int and int?

Tags: c++, casting, integer-overflow, openvms

I have an 8-character `string` representing a hexadecimal number and I need to convert it to an `int`.  This conversion has to preserve the bit pattern for strings `"80000000"` and higher, i.e., those numbers should come out negative.  Unfortunately, the naive solution:

```
int hex_str_to_int(const string hexStr)
{    
    stringstream strm;
    strm << hex << hexStr;
    unsigned int val = 0;
    strm >> val;
    return static_cast<int>(val);
}
```

doesn't work for my compiler if `val > MAX_INT` (the returned value is 0).  Changing the type of val to `int` also results in a 0 for the larger numbers.  I've tried several different solutions from various answers here on SO and haven't been successful yet.

Here's what I do know:

- I'm using HP's C++ compiler on OpenVMS (using, I believe, an Itanium processor).
- `sizeof(int)` will be at least 4 on every architecture my code will run on.
- Casting from a number > INT_MAX to int is implementation-defined. On my machine, it usually results in a 0 but interestingly casting from `long` to `int` results in `INT_MAX` when the value is too big.

This is surprisingly difficult to do correctly, or at least it has been for me.  Does anyone know of a **portable** solution to this?

**Update:**

Changing `static_cast` to `reinterpret_cast` results in a compiler error.  A comment prompted me to try a C-style cast: `return (int)val` in the code above, and it worked.  *On this machine.*  Will that still be safe on other architectures?

Comment: Can't just use `(int)val`? However, "Changing the type of val to `int` also results in a 0...." means issue might be from `>>`? (I have no idea really, I don't use C++ ;-)

Comment: Signed integer overflow isn't implementation-defined, its undefined.

Comment: @derobert, thanks, I wasn't sure.  I knew it wasn't good.  Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Converting from unsigned to signed is implementation defined if the unsigned number is not in the range of the signed type.

Comment: @derobert : This isn't signed overflow though, this is integral conversion, the result of which _is_ implementation-defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While there are ways to do this using casts and conversions, most rely on undefined behavior that happen to have well-defined behaviors on some machines / with some compilers. Instead of relying on undefined behavior, copy the data:

```
int signed_val;
std::memcpy (&signed_val, &val, sizeof(int));
return signed_val;
```

Comment: Implementation-defined behavior, not undefined.

Comment: @ildjarn: One widely used approach is `return *(int*)(&val);` This isn't implementation-defined behavior. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah, that's equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`, which is indeed UB; I assumed you were referring to the `static_cast` in the OP's question, whose behavior is implementation-defined.

Comment: Why is it undefined behavior?

Comment: This is surprisingly fast with modern compilers.

Comment: C++20 will have `bit_cast` which effectively does the same thing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast

Comment: @EmileCormier - It's fairly fast even at the lowest optimization level as the call to `memcpy` does not occur; I tested with multiple compilers. At anything but the lowest optimization level it's extremely fast because the working variable (`signed_val` in my answer) gets optimized away. I suspect these kinds of optimizations were in place well before I wrote the above answer 9+ years ago. The as-if rule was certainly in place even with the original version of the standard. That is the rule that enables the elimination of the call to `memcpy`.

Comment: @Friedrich - It's undefined because the standard very explicitly says so. Doing so violates C++'s strict aliasing rule, which is even stricter than C's strict aliasing rule. The C-style cast `return *(int*)(&val)` is undefined behavior even in C.

Comment: @DavidHammen It's only recently I've encountered a similar problem to the OP and discovered that compilers can optimize away memcpy. Thanks for pointing out that compilers knew that trick long ago.

Answer (score 15):

Quoting the C++03 standard, §4.7/3 (Integral Conversions):

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); **otherwise, the value is implementation-defined**.

Because the result is implementation-defined, by definition it is impossible for there to be a truly *portable* solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can negate an unsigned twos-complement number by taking the complement and adding one. So let's do that for negatives:

```
if (val < 0x80000000) // positive values need no conversion
  return val;
if (val == 0x80000000) // Complement-and-addition will overflow, so special case this
  return -0x80000000; // aka INT_MIN
else
  return -(int)(~val + 1);
```

This assumes that your ints are represented with 32-bit twos-complement representation (or have similar range). It does not rely on any undefined behavior related to signed integer overflow (note that the behavior of *unsigned* integer overflow is well-defined - although that should not happen here either!).

Note that if your ints are not 32-bit, things get more complex. You may need to use something like `~(~0U >> 1)` instead of `0x80000000`. Further, if your ints are no twos-complement, you may have overflow issues on certain values (for example, on a ones-complement machine, `-0x80000000` cannot be represented in a 32-bit signed integer). However, non-twos-complement machines are very rare today, so this is unlikely to be a problem.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure this code is likely to run in a 64-bit environment someday. Hard-coding bit patterns like that is probably not a good idea. This solution works on this machine though.

Comment: Most 64-bit environments use 32-bit ints. In any case, though, you can use `~(~(unsigned yourinttype)0 >> 1)` to find the right value for other unsigned integer types (eg, `unsigned long long`)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution that worked for me:

```
if (val <= INT_MAX) {
    return static_cast<int>(val);
}
else {
    int ret = static_cast<int>(val & ~INT_MIN);
    return ret | INT_MIN;
}
```

If I mask off the high bit, I avoid overflow when casting.  I can then OR it back safely.

Answer (score 4):

C++20 will have [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) that copies bits verbatim:

```
#include <bit>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = -42;
    auto u = std::bit_cast<unsigned>(i);
    // Prints 4294967254 on two's compliment platforms where int is 32 bits
    std::cout << u << "\n";

    auto roundtripped = std::bit_cast<int>(u);
    assert(roundtripped == i);
    std::cout << roundtripped << "\n"; // Prints -42

    return 0;
}
```

cppreference shows an [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) of how one can implement their own `bit_cast` in terms of `memcpy` (under Notes).

While OpenVMS is not likely to gain C++20 support anytime soon, I hope this answer helps someone arriving at the same question via internet search.

Comment: It's worth noting that the memcpy approach matches this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7602036/46821

Answer (score -2):

```
unsigned int u = ~0U;
int s = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&u); // -1
```

Сontrariwise:

```
int s = -1;
unsigned int u = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&s); // all ones
```