# Converting Signed to Unsigned and vice versa

Tags: c++, linux, unsigned

I have to implement two functions that convert signed to unsigned and vice versa.  I am using c++11 and Linux.

The system is two's complement and can take char, int, long etc.. The interface must be as stated and I have tried to implement something.  Are there better ways to do this?  Are these correct? How can I change the implementation based on the number of bits?  I need some advice.

```
uint32_t signedToUnsigned(int32_t x, uint8_t bits)
{
    return ( x > 0 ? x:-x);
}

int32_t unsignedToSigned(uint32_t x, uint8_t bits)
{
    if(x <= INT_MAX )
        return static_cast<int>(x);

    if(x >= INT_MIN)
        return static_cast<int>(x - INT_MIN)+ INT_MIN;
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR");
        return x;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I need to specifiy the bits as this will be used with HW.  So, I may need to limit the value in the return type to 18bits or 4 etc...

Comment: what's the use of second argument bits here?

Comment: Your `unsignedToSigned()` function is broken. Think it through for a case where `x` is larger than `INT_MAX` or smaller than `INT_MIN`, and you will see what I mean.

If your argument is `int32_t` (fixed 32 bits), that pretty much *decides* how many bits there are, doesn't it?

All in all, hard to tell what your question is, really...

Comment: Maybe nothing, I was wondering if I need to change the code based on the type used, like int or char etc..

Comment: @user1876942: I am not sure what these functions should be used for *at all*, since two's complement already *has* rather nice handling of unsigned-signed-unsigned casting already...

Comment: @user1876942 This condition if(x >= INT_MIN) is always equal to true because UINT_MIN is equal to 0 and in any case is greater than INT_MIN. So the next else statement has no sense.:)

Comment: @DevSolar, can you give an example?

Comment: "Are these correct?" Yes, for certain special values of "correct". You need to **define** what the conversion should do in case of target type being unable to represent the value, then check your implementation against your definition.

Comment: @@user1876942 How are you going to convert an unsigned value to signed value if the unsigned value is greater than INT_MAX?

Comment: @user1876942: Not really, because I cannot figure out what your `unsignedToSigned()` function is *supposed* to do. (What it *does* do makes no sense at all.) So: What's wrong with simply `static_cast<int>()` that `unsignedToSigned()` should be fixing?

Comment: @DevSolar, Will that always work?  For some reason I thought not.  I will need to check if that is OK.  Simpler anyhow.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1876942: I don't know if it will "work" *because you are not clear about what your requirements are and your current implementation is bugged.*

Comment: @user1876942 Your edit does not clarify your expectations. If you are converting a negative number to unsigned you want its absolute value? If you are converting a unsigned number greater than the max signed number, you want what? If returning too few bits to represent the number do you just want to preserve the least-significant-bits as your return value? If returning too few bits to represent a signed number do you want to preserve the sign in the bits returned as well? Please add these expectations to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having dependency of no of bits have overloaded functions as:

```
uint32_t signedToUnsigned(int32_t x);
uint64_t signedToUnsigned(int64_t x);
uint16_t signedToUnsigned(int16_t x);
```

and so on.
However, simple static_cast should do, please read: [How does one safely static_cast between unsigned int and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601731/how-does-one-safely-static-cast-between-unsigned-int-and-int)

Comment: I will check out that static_cast.  What about going the other way, signedToUnsigned?

Comment: similarly you can go for signedToUnsigned

Comment: @user1876942: Your `signedToUnsigned()` is implemented as [`std::abs()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) (for "absolute value") in the standard library (<cstdlib>).

Comment: Std::abs does not support 16bit.  Therefore -32768 gives 32768 but in 16bit it should be 32767.

Comment: @user1876942 I suspect that you are using the C abs function included in `cmath`. At the top of your file you should `#include <complex>` which will give you the templatized C++ version of `std::abs` and return `32767`.

Comment: @Jonathan,do you know if there is a way to specifiy the number of bits to limit the operation to?  So, 4bit, 12, or 18 etc..  As I will use it with HW registers.

Comment: @user1876942 It sounds like what you really want is (`std::bitset`)[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/]. You can see the operators here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/operators/. It sounds like you wanna play special attention to `operator~`.

Comment: @user1876942 I'd also recommend that you take the time to go through and accept answers on your questions. A lot of people are putting in time helping you. The least you can do is also contribute by accepting answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a number to survive a round trip your functions are not good.

For example: `std::cout << unsignedToSigned( signedToUnsigned( -13, 0 ), 0 ); // prints 13 NOT -13`

`static_cast` will survive the round trip: `std::cout << static_cast< int32_t >( static_cast< uint32_t >( -13 ) ); // prints -13`

So I think `static_cast` is what you want unless you can update the question with a clearer specification.