# Signed integer to unsigned and back?

Tags: c++, casting, type-punning

I would like to store a signed `int32` into an unsigned `uint32` such that I can extract a `int32` from it later.  The value of the `uint32` itself isn't used when it stores an integer like this, but I can't use a union in this case unfortunately. The way I currently do this is by simply converting it:

```
int32  signedVar   = -500;
uint32 unsignedVar = uint32(signedVar);
func(int32(unsignedVar)); // should supply the function with -500
```

This appears to work, but I'm afraid it might not be portable, and that there might be needless conversions happening behind the scenes for what I'm hoping is a no-op.

Is -500 or any other negative number guaranteed to survive this conversion? If not, is there a "painless" (none of the types are changed, only the conversion method) alternative?

Edit: I'm most concerned with making sure the value in `int32` is preserved in a `uint32` so it can be used as a `int32` of the same value later, the `uint32` version is never used.  (editing because SO asked me to explain how this isn't a duplicate of another question; it doesn't specify what the results of the conversion should look like, or that it needs to be symmetrical like this, making it too general to be applied here)

Comment: Why do you need to go there and back again?

Comment: use reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @NathanOliver - tbh, laziness.  There's an edge case where there can be a negative index into an array, and I don't want to write the machinery into the pipeline to deal with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Signed to Unsigned and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036504/converting-signed-to-unsigned-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Ah.  You may to to give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150449/efficient-unsigned-to-signed-cast-avoiding-implementation-defined-behavior

Comment: @SlardarZhang - will `signedVar == *reinterpret_cast<int32*>(&(*reinterpret_cast<uint32*>(&signedVar)));` always be true? (wacky code but y'know what I mean!)

Comment: @JonathanMee I do not think that works in all cases.  If your machine does not have a twos-compliment signed integer(this is not required) I do not think it works.

Comment: @SlardarZhang `static_cast` is what you want see standard section 4.7.2 You do not want `reinterpret_cast` see standard section 5.2.10.3.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fascinating, I've been digging through the standard and it seems you're right without 2's compliment truncation can occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your machine uses 1s-complement or sign-magnitude arithmetic (which is allowed by the C standard at least; not sure about C++), then this double conversion will convert the value -0 into 0.  If your machine uses 2s complement, then this will be fine.

That said, I'm not aware of any machine built in the last 30 years that uses anything other than 2s complement for arithmetic.